# How to create colspan from DataGridColumn in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, actionscript

I want to make merge 2 columns into 1 column just like HTML has colspans attribute in table. Please do give a simple example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group header columns in a Datagrid together by using the AdvancedDataGrid component, here is an example.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- dpcontrols/adg/ColumnGroupADG.mxml -->
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            // Import the data used by the AdvancedDataGrid control. 
            include "SimpleFlatData.as";
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="myADG"
        dataProvider="{dpFlat}"
        width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:groupedColumns>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Region"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Territory"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Territory_Rep"
                headerText="Territory Rep"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup headerText="Revenues">    
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Actual"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Estimate"/>
            </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup>    
        </mx:groupedColumns>
   </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
</s:Application>
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7bf0.html